# Loop through records and create .txt files from batches

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have below code where I would like to create .txt files only instead of excel files. Below will take records from Sheet1 separate them by 47k rows, paste it into template and will create .txt file (format without commas, print method, not overwriting existing txt files in the folder, each filename to be "Part"& "sequence number", for ex. "Part 1" ) and then repeat until all records from Sheet1 gone into txt files. I need help with creating a loop which will create txt file & paste the records into txt files

```
     Sub FillTemplate(c As Long)
        Dim Lrow1A, c, start, finish as Long
        Dim TV As Variant
        
        ' this part divides all records by 47k and rounds up
        Lrow1A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        TV = Lrow1A / 47000
        TV = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(TV, 0)
        
        ' this part copies records (divided by batches of 47k) into template
        start = ((c - 1) * 47000) + 2
        finish = (c * 47000) + 1
        
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(start, 1), Cells(finish, 1)).Copy
        Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End Sub
        
        Sub new_template(c As Long)

' Need help here: How to make macro create new text files? 
'at the moment it overwrites existing text files in a folder
        
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim WBname, WBname1 As String
        
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
        WBname = wb.FullName 'create new workbook to rename previous one
        
        WBname1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
        Workbooks("Sum.xlsm").Activate
        Worksheets("Template").Select
        Range("A:R").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks(WBname1).Activate
        Columns(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\D\folder\Part " & c & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End Sub
        
        Sub Finalcode()
        
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To TV
    
    Call FillTemplate(c)
    Call new_template(c)
    
    
    Next c
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
file1 = ThisWorkbook.Name

file1 = Replace(file1, ".xlsm", "")
Debug.Print file1

filepath = "C:\Billing3\"    '<<< change me
j1 = 1
file2 = filepath & file1 & j1 & ".txt"
Set outfile = fs.OpenTextFile(file2, 8)
lrow = 250000
Sheets(1).Select

For i1 = 1 To lrow
    text1 = Cells(i1, 1)
    outfile.WriteLine text1

    If Int(i1 / 47000) = i1 / 47000 Then
        outfile.Close
        j1 = j1 + 1
        file2 = filepath & file1 & j1 & ".txt"
        Set outfile = fs.CreateTextFile(file2, 8)
    End If
    
Next
outfile.Close`
```

Filesystemobject can be used to deal with text and csv files
The above code will copy column A from 1st sheet in batches of 47000 up to a maximum of lrow (set at 250000 which can be changed)

Comment: Hi many thanks for this however the input data from 1st sheet should be copied in batches into the 2nd sheet which is the template and has additional data and text files to be created based on that 2nd sheet, how can we change it?

Comment: So 1st sheet has whole pile of data 100k plus rows in first column, the code should take records from 1st sheet in batches - every 47k and paste it into 2nd sheet starting from cell I1 - this is the template with records from 1st sheet and also has additional data. After data of 47k records was copied into the 2nd sheet text files should be created until all records from 1st sheet finished. You can see the logic if you'll have a look into my initial code

Comment: Sorry, my second post may be more helpful than the first

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub new_template(c As Long)

Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
file2 = "\\D\folder\Part " & c & ".txt"
Set Outfile = fs.OpenTextFile(file2, 8)

Worksheets("Template").Select
For r1 = 1 to 47000
    Text1 = cells(r1, 1)   'cell in row r1, column 1   (or A)
    For c1 = 2 to 18   ‘run from columns 2 to 18  (B to R)
        Text1 = Text1 & vbtab & cells(r1, c1)   ‘vbtab is the tab delimiter
    Next
        'Text1=left(Text1, Len(Text1)-1) 'remove last tab which is not be used
    Outfile.writeline Text1
Next
Outfile.close

End sub
```

Comment: I get variable not defined for Text1=“”

Comment: Variable not defined for Outfile - should it be "dim"-ed as string?

Comment: Try debug.print file2      and check what appears in watch window (Ctrl G)    I'll try some debugging on the Text1 part

Comment: Hi, I have just modified "Sub new_template()" so now there are no xls files created and code works fine(pls. see my initial macro above), the only issue is that new text files created are overwriting the existing ones. How can it be changed?

Comment: fs.OpenTextFile(file2, 8)  '8 means append, 1 is read and 2 rewrite

FileExists = Dir(file2)
If FileExists <> "" then  'file exists already

Comment: I am writing about the script posted by me, I have updated it but it keep overwriting text files. Concerning your last post it is not working as there are variables to be declared...

Comment: fs; file2; Outfile; r1; Text1;c1; - all of them should be declared, string, long, object etc.

Comment: sorry, r1 and c1 are int or long;     Text1 and file2 are strings;     set fs = ....    and set Outfile = .....     both declare at the same time as creating but can be written differently eg dim fs as new scripting.filesystemobject

Comment: I am getting compile error: User-defined type not defined for 
Dim fs  As New scripting.filesystemobject
Dim Outfile As New scripting.filesystemobject

Comment: I have added MS Scripting Runtime reference from tools and above compile error is gone, now I am receiving "Compile error: Method or data member not found" on -  Outfile.writeline Text1 - There is no such method for Outfile as writeline

Comment: could you please post your updated version of code this one is not working....

Comment: Ok, the whole story with error was I had just to dim outfile.. Can you tell me why do you need a loop in ws called Template? I do not need a loop on Template the loop goes before the data is copied into worksheet named Template, and from there I just need text files to be created based on the Template worksheet

Comment: From the original code, columns A to R were copied and pasted into the new file. I've not found an equivalent way to do this from Excel to text file though in theory a clipboard object could be used. Instead it starts at row  1, then concatenates the cells A1, B1, C1, ..., R1 into variable Text1 and then writes Text1 out to the text file. Then it repeats for row2, row3, .... , row 47000.

Comment: I was thinking it would rather be a straight forward copy & paste from the "template" worksheet into a text file... that looping slows down the macro

Comment: Application.screenupdating = false       can help here if there are a lot of formulae in one of the Excel. sheets.

Comment: I will be checking the whole code next couple of days will let you know!